# Flutter Location Package: 'onLocationChanged' method listen changes but always return the same coordinates on IOS

Tags: ios, flutter

Using location ^4.4.0 and listen location changes but always returning the same location coordinates on IOS.

```
Location location = Location();

location.onLocationChanged.listen((LocationData currentLocation) {
     print('{"latitude": "${currentLocation.latitude}", "longitude": "${currentLocation.longitude}"}');
}
```

I've made the setup on IOS from the package and retrieving permissions with permission_handler package. On Android is working fine but on IOS always return the same coordinates.

The listen is working by retrieving data, but the coordinates should change because i'm testing it on a real device - iPhone XR with IOS 16.3.

```
** flutter doctor -v **

[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.3, on macOS 12.6 21G115 darwin-x64, locale en-PT)
    • Flutter version 3.7.3 on channel stable at /Users/tiago/Code/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 9944297138 (6 days ago), 2023-02-08 15:46:04 -0800
    • Engine revision 248290d6d5
    • Dart version 2.19.2
    • DevTools version 2.20.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/tiago/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 30.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/tiago/Android/Sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.0.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14A400
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.75.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
```

Any advice on that?

Comment: Have you set the permissions accordingly & the run time permission too ?

Comment: i believe this has to do with permissions on IOS, kindly go through the Location package docs, see onLocationChanged